# Erro de Tela JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Quando eu clico para abrir a tela de clientes aparece esse erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Erro:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    file:/C:/Users/Alvaro%20Silva/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PrimeiroProjeto/dist/run6487327/PrimeiroProjeto.jar!/javafxmlmvc/view/FXMLAnchorPaneCadastrosClientes.fxml:18

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at javafxmlmvc.view.FXMLDocumentController.handleMenuItemcadClientes(FXMLDocumentController.java:69)
        ... 53 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TableView field javafxmlmvc.view.FXMLAnchorPaneCadastrosClientesController.tabela to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        ... 61 more enter code here`
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxmlmvc.view.FXMLAnchorPaneCadastrosClientesController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3294314381270903" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="403.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane fx:id="tabela" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="234.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tabelaCliente" prefHeight="373.0" prefWidth="195.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tabelaColunaClienteNome" prefWidth="97.0" text="Nome" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tabelaColunaClienteCpf" prefWidth="96.0" text="CPF" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="135.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Detalhes do Cliente">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <GridPane layoutX="101.0" layoutY="111.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Código" />
                        <Label text="Nome" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="CPF" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Telefone" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label fx:id="lblCodigo" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Label fx:id="lblNome" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label fx:id="lblCpf" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label fx:id="lblTelefone" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <Button fx:id="btnInserir" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="285.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Inserir" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnAlterar" layoutX="168.0" layoutY="285.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Alterar " />
                  <Button fx:id="btnExcluir" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="285.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Excluir" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou postar o controller, pode ser algum componente que voce não mapeou o id no seu .fxml ou não informou a anotação @FXML sobre o componente no controller